# Simple demonstration of degrees of freedom of $O(1,3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

In the real valued matrix representation of $O(1,3)$, the group elements are the set of real valued 4 by 4 matrices $M$ such that
$$ 
M^T \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is it possible to show that with a matrix of the form
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
y_{00} & A_{01} & A_{02} & A_{03} \\
y_{10} & y_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\
y_{20} & y_{21} & y_{22} & A_{23} \\
y_{30} & y_{31} & y_{32} & y_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that given any values for the $A_{??}$ terms
it is always possible to solve for values of the $y_{??}$ terms to satisfy the quadratic form constraint?

This would demonstrate there are at least 6 continuous degrees of freedom.

At best the solution will not be unique because there are still discrete degrees of freedom.  So if it is easier to mod out $Z_2 \times Z_2$ and work with $SO^+(1,3)$ that is fine too (but I wasn't sure the best way to represent those restrictions as a linear algebra constraint). If that is possible as well, that would be even better as it would show there are exactly 6 continuous degrees of freedom.

Comment: There are much better ways to prove that this Lie group is 6-dimensional. For instance, linearize the equation $M^TJM=J$ (with $J=diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$). This gives you a linear subspace in the space of $4\times 4$ matrices, called the Lie algebra of $O(1,3)$. The dimension of this Lie algebra is 6, so is the dimension of $O(1,3)$. I suggest you try this method.

Comment: Here are some nice notes on that approach: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/geombchap14.pdf

Answer (score 2):

While there are six degrees of freedom, these cannot be directly taken from some matrix elements as hoped in the question.

Consider for instance:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
y_{00} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
y_{10} & y_{11} & 1 & 1 \\
y_{20} & y_{21} & y_{22} & 1 \\
y_{30} & y_{31} & y_{32} & y_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$$
This has no real value solutions for the $y$ terms.

To prove this, it will be helpful to introduce some notation and break $M$ into blocks
$$ \mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix}a & \mathbf{b}^T\\\mathbf{c} & \mathbf{D}\end{bmatrix}
\,, \quad
\mathbf{N} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\mathbf{I}\end{bmatrix}
\,, \quad
\mathbf{M}^T \mathbf{N} \mathbf{M} = \mathbf{N}.
$$
Expanding out the block equations
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{N} &=& \mathbf{M}^T \mathbf{N} \mathbf{M}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\mathbf{I}\end{bmatrix} &=& 
\begin{bmatrix}a & \mathbf{c}^T \\ \mathbf{b} & \mathbf{D}^T\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\mathbf{I}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a & \mathbf{b}^T \\ \mathbf{c} & \mathbf{D}\end{bmatrix}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\mathbf{I}\end{bmatrix} &=& 
\begin{bmatrix}
(a^2 - \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{c}) & (a \mathbf{b}^T - \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{D})\\
(\mathbf{b}a - \mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{c}) & (\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^T - \mathbf{D}^T\mathbf{D})
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Note that $M$ also satisfies the constraint with the transpose operation moved to the other side.
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
M^T N M &=& N \\
(M N) M^T N M &=& (M N) N = M \\
(M N M^T) N M &=& M \\
(M N M^T) N &=& I \quad \text{(allowed because $\det{M}=\pm1$ and so is invertible)}\\
M N M^T &=& N
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Expanding out the block equations
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{N} &=& \mathbf{M} \mathbf{N} \mathbf{M}^T 
\\
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\mathbf{I}\end{bmatrix} &=& 
\begin{bmatrix}a & \mathbf{b}^T \\ \mathbf{c} & \mathbf{D}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\mathbf{I}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a & \mathbf{c}^T \\ \mathbf{b} & \mathbf{D}^T\end{bmatrix}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\mathbf{I}\end{bmatrix} &=& 
\begin{bmatrix}
(a^2 - \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{b}) & (a \mathbf{c}^T - \mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{D}^T)\\
(\mathbf{c}a - \mathbf{D} \mathbf{b}) & (\mathbf{c}\mathbf{c}^T - \mathbf{D}\mathbf{D}^T)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Together this shows $\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{b} = a^2 - 1$. For the counter-example this means if there was a solution it would be of the form
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{M} &=& \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & y_{11} & 1 & 1 \\
0 & y_{21} & y_{22} & 1 \\
0 & y_{31} & y_{32} & y_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\mathbf{I} &=& \mathbf{D}\mathbf{D}^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{11} & 1 & 1 \\
y_{21} & y_{22} & 1 \\
y_{31} & y_{32} & y_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{11} & y_{21} & y_{31} \\
1 & y_{22} & y_{32} \\
1 & 1 & y_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Which has no real valued solution, since it requires $y_{11}^2 + 2 = 1$.

---

If you restrict the range of the $A_{??}$ terms to a small range, it should be possible to get a *subset* of the matrices if you really want to express the freedom directly in the matrix elements, but only need a small neighborhood.

Here is such a solution, written in python, if you restrict the range of the inputs to $[-1/2,+1/2]$.

```
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np

def sq(x):
    return x*x

def calcM(tup6,scale_divisor=1):
    '''calculates a Lorentz matrix containing supplied six real values

    Input:
      tuple of 6 real values restricted to range [-1/2,1/2]
      The actual range is larger, but not worth trying to specify.
      For laziness purposes, can scale all values before processing.
    Output:
      a Lorentz matrix with values above/right of diagonal equal
      to the 6 input values

    Note:
      this only works for a subset of Lorentz matrices, mainly intended for
      small parameter matrices in the neighborhood of the identity
    '''
    x,y,z,p,q,t = map(lambda x: (1.0*x)/scale_divisor, tup6)

    a = sqrt(1 + x*x + y*y + z*z)
    w = sqrt(1 + z*z - q*q - t*t)

    d = 1 + z*z + y*y - p*p - q*q - sq(y*q-p*z)
    v = (-w*(p*q-y*z) - t*sqrt(d))/(1+z*z-q*q)

    d = (1 + z*z - q*q)*(1 + y*y - p*p) - sq(y*z-p*q)
    s = (t*(y*z-p*q) + w*sqrt(d))/(w*w+t*t)

    d = (a*a-x*x)*(1 - p*p - q*q) + sq((y*p+z*q))
    m = (x*(y*p+z*q) + a*sqrt(d))/(a*a-x*x)

    r = (x*(y*w-z*v) -m*(p*w-q*v))/(s*w - t*v)
    u = (x*z - m*q - r*t)/w

    m10 = (m*x + p*y + q*z)/a
    m20 = (r*x + s*y + t*z)/a
    m30 = (u*x + v*y + w*z)/a

    return np.matrix([[a,x,y,z],
                    [m10,m,p,q],
                    [m20,r,s,t],
                    [m30,u,v,w]])
```